# regex how to match except simple or duple quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

```
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('CALCULO_AGIL_DT_POSTO');
```

I need this text:

```
CALCULO_AGIL_DT_POSTO
```

I have this regex in PHP:

`'(?<=SYS\.DBMS_SCHEDULER\.RUN_JOB\()[^'].*(?<=\))`

but it does not work properly.

Comment: You almost got it. Missing a simple quote inside your lookbehind and your lookahead. And remove the `.` just after your character class.

Comment: `simple or duple quotes` should be `single or double quotes`, or can you provide more samples showing simple quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the need for a look ahead here.

Just make a simple pattern like this:

```
$pattern = "/SYS\.DBMS_SCHEDULER\.RUN_JOB\([\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]\)\;/";
```

It will match what is in exactly this string between the `(` and `'`.
I made it lazy just in case it finds another `')` somewhere else.

https://regex101.com/r/c9Kl3E/2

Edit noticed now in your title you need to be able to match both `'` and `"`.
Added that to the regex `[\'\"]`

Answer (score 0):

this one should work too, get you gonna need group 2 :

```
^(.+?')([a-zA-Z_]+)?('.+)$
```